# How to pass dynamic parameters in Powershell?

Tags: dynamic, powershell, parameters

I want to call an existing commandlet with a dynamic number of parameters.

So instead of doing this (taking write-host as an example), I would like to do it the smart way.

```
# these are the dynamic parameters which maybe get passed into my function or script
# they would be $null be default of course
$forecolor = 'Green'
$newline = $true

# now build the "dynamic" write-host...
if ($forecolor) {
    if ($newline) {
        write-host -fore $forecolor "Hello world"
    }
    else {
        write-host -fore $forecolor "Hello world" -nonewline
    }
}
else {
    if ($newline) {
        write-host "Hello world"
    }
    else {
        write-host "Hello world" -nonewline
    }
}
```

**This of course is very ugly. Help me make it prettier!**

I already tried just setting `$forecolor = '-fore Green'` which only outputs *"-fore Green Hello world"*. I could think of passing a list of arguments to a function and for each argument in the list add the according parameter - I just don't know how to hold the parameters.

Comment: Have you had a look at parameter sets? http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/06/30/use-parameter-sets-to-simplify-powershell-commands.aspx

Comment: David, how would those help here? I'm confused.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can just pass your variables as arguments to `Write-Host`:

```
Write-Host -Fore $forecolor -NoNewLine:(!$newline) 'Hello World'
```

For a truly dynamic way you can use a hashtable:

```
$params = @{ NoNewLine = $true; ForegroundColor = 'Green' }
```

and then use the splat operator

```
Write-Host @params Hello World
```

You can add parameters and their values to the hashtable as you like before calling `Write-Host` that way.

Comment: **Awesome!** Here's an article about splatting: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg675931.aspx never heard of that wizardry before. Thanks.

Comment: I have been working for years with PowerShell and have never heard about this. Now finally, I did: Great feature!

Comment: Your last example already implies this, but just for clarity, you can mix and match as well: `Write-Host @params Hello World -BackgroundColor White`